# How to animate multiple elements at the same time?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I am working on a header animation, when the class `collapseTest` is added to the header with JS. I have done this and you can see a live example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPEpyM

Unfortunately, when you take a look at my live code, you will see that the left part, where the menu is positioned, doesn't animate at the same time as the bottom of the green bar beside them. I want to animate both bottoms, the menu square and the green block at the same time. Is this possible? And how can I achieve this?

For the animation I used the css transition property:

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
```

I have play with the `duration` of the transition of both, the menu block and the rest of it (the white and green bar beside the menu), but I can't get it animate synchroon.

I add these animations on the menu, the white bar on the top and the green one below it when the class `collapseTest` is added to the header element with JS:

```
function explode() {
    $('header').addClass('collapseTest');
};

setTimeout(explode, 800);
```

An example of the css declaration:

```
#header.collapseTest .toggle-menu {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.81s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.81s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.81s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.81s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

If there are any questions, don't hesitate to leave a comment below.
Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your class

```
#header.collapseTest .top {
height: 0;
margin: -1px;

-webkit-transition: all 0.935s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.935s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.935s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 0.935s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

.......

As transition complete time for different values are same there for we can do it by reducing speed of one element to adjust the speed .

Or

We can do it by developing a structure inside one element and apply transition on parent element so that the child elements will look great while transition. Thanks

Comment: Can you include a live demo? So other can see the working solution to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938258/css-transition-on-multiple-elements                                                                                                                                         Hope it will help you .

Comment: Just change your duration to: `0.779s`. Now it will animate almost synchrone with the rest of the elements. Thanks

Comment: @Caspert , i am not sure manually editing the trasition is the way to go , check my answer !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

You're going to find this hard to believe, but there seems to be an issue in how the transition is taking place. Somehow if you mix `%` and `pixels`, the transition, does seem to work in tandem (though its still synchronous).

What I mean by that is, on your navigation, you animate the height and so also on the `div.bottom`, the problem is one of them has a pixel based height and the other has a `%` based height. So to get what you want i.e. both the elements should animate in the same way, change the height of both the elements to pixel based or `%` based.

Change the below style:

```
#header > div {
    height: 50%;  // see how this is percentage based 
    width: calc(100% - 180px)!important;
    padding-left: 26px;
    display: table;
}
```

To:

```
#header > div {
    height: 75px;  // 75px is = 50% in your case, might hurt responsive design !!
    width: calc(100% - 180px)!important;
    padding-left: 26px;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: I already try that, but than the right part is shrinking faster then the menu block, and that's my issue. It should be synchroon animated..

Comment: @Caspert found the solution ! check my edited answer !